# Expression Working in debugger but not in code

Tags: swift, url, nsurlcomponents

So here's my code:

```swift
let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "foo", value: "bar")]

var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://example.com/fiz")
urlComponents?.queryItems = queryItems

print(urlComponents?.url?.absoluteString)
```

The printed string is `http://example.com/fiz`. But if a put a breakpoint before the print and type in debugger:

```
expression urlComponents?.queryItems = queryItems
```

The printed string will be `http://example.com/fiz?foo=bar`

Also, if I force (as bellow) the unwrap of the urlComponent, it's working

```swift
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://example.com/fiz")!
```

Is that a normal behaviour ?

Comment: WFM in an Xcode 12 playground.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 12 too :/